# URI encode not encoding URLs (turning latter parts of https:// into encoded characters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, encoding, url-encoding, uriencoding

Here's my output:

```
URI.encode("http://localhost:3000/membership?referer_invite_code=a03478&fee=UVYA")
=> "http://localhost:3000/membership?referer_invite_code=a03478&fee=UVYA" 

But I need output to be:
=> "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000..."
```

The reason is because I'm trying to do an embedded twitter link and twitter doesn't do well with ampersands, so as long as the encoding doesn't replace the `&` for the last fee parameter with `%26` it won't work. How do I fix this?

**WORKING SOLUTION**

```
Rack::Utils.escape("http://localhost:3000/membership?referer_invite_code=a03478&fee=UVYA")
```

But I guess I'm just curious why `URI.encode` did not work

Answer (score 1):

You should use `URI.encode_www_form_component` for this purpose instead:

```
URI.encode_www_form_component "http://localhost:3000/membership?referer_invite_code=a03478&fee=UVYA"
=> "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fmembership%3Freferer_invite_code%3Da03478%26fee%3DUVYA"
```

It seems that `URI.encode` is intended to encode an entire URI *for use as a URI*, rather than for use as a parameter *within* a URI. It is only meant to protect against the use of illegal characters in a URI - not to properly encode URI parameters - so by default it does not encode the reserved characters listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters).

You can find more information in the [RubyDoc entry for URI::Escape](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html). `URI.escape` takes an optional regular expression as a second argument. The regex specifies which characters should be percent-encoded in the result. If omitted, the default of `URI::UNSAFE` is used. In MRI 2.3.1, this amounts to the following:

`/[^\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&=+$,\[\]]/`

As you can see, this will not match any of the reserved characters for a URI. What it will do is protect you from constructing and using a URI that is illegal. For example:

```
URI.encode "https://test.com"
=> "https://test.com"

URI.encode "https://testçĕÅ.com/"
=> "https://test%C3%A7%C4%95%C3%85.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you forgot before it

```
require 'uri'
```